# PayPal IPN and AutoReturn

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an ipn listener that update my transactions (from pending to completed) and my contracts payments from finished to paid. This is perfect! I has also a return page... From PayPal to my site... This page show "thanks" and "button to allow download their last paid online contract" (paid with PayPal). My problem is that.... Ipn listener sometimes comes 3 seconds after my return page is shown to the the user....

In my return page in this case. Has the transaction and contract unpaid... And when ipn listener catch the results... Then this transaction and contract change to paid status. But ipn listener is executed at back-end. In my server. And my return page was shown 3 o 2 seconds before to my user. What can I do?

Should I add a timer (a delay) in my return page waiting until ipn updates my transaction and contract status? And then, show to the user a button "you can download your last paid contract!". Or better I should forget this step. And in my return page always without wait show to user "thanks for your payment". "you can download your last paid contract!"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I also have my return page wait for the IPN notification to come into my server, and you can definitely make that work if you do it right.

Initially, the return page polls on a field in my back-end database that the IPN handler updates.  Then, when the return page sees that field update, the customer gets his 'here are the items you paid for' button.

I also have a one minute timeout on this process.  When that expires (although I can't remember the last time that actually happened), I display a catch-all error message ('There was a problem processing your transaction') and invite the customer to contact me for help.

I also tell them that their license key (which is what they are buying, in my case) might be on its way by email, since, usually, it is. IPN notifications can sometimes take a little while to arrive for some reason but my IPN handler sends out a confirmation email as a backup so they will get that in due course.  That usually sorts things out, I rarely need to get directly involved.

If PayPal puts the transaction on hold, it doesn't seem to ever forward the customer to the return page (I have certainly never seen that happen).  Instead, I assume it lets the customer know that he must wait for the funds to clear and leaves it at that.

An IPN notification *does* get sent however when the transaction eventually clears, and then you can have your handler send that email.

Lest this sounds like a lot of work, you should be sending an email from your IPN handler anyway since customers like to have a record of their purchases.  Once you put that mechanism in place, the rest is easy.

**Note:** Watch out for IPN transactions flagged as 'echeque'.  **The funds haven't cleared yet**, you will get another notification when they do.  *Then* you can send them their contract by email.  If memory serves,this *does* forward them to your return page so you have to handle that by letting them know that they must wait.  In practise, this doesn't seem to happen very often.

**Suggestion:**  have your scripts send *you* an email when something unexpected happens.  This has saved my bacon more than once when PayPal have changed the names of the fields passed to the IPN handler for no obvious reason.

**Summary:** This is a practical, experience-based write-up of the way my website works, and it works well.  I hope readers of this post find it helpful, despite the mysterious downvotes.

Comment: This does not follow on from my answering any way. You should not have it wait. It could takes weeks, or forever. You should regard return from Paypal and receipt of the money as two independent events. I have already made that quite clear. This is not a technical issue, or UI design issue. It is a business issue.

Comment: @EJP I am beginning to dislike you.  I posted what _I_ do on _my_ site because it works for _me_.  The OP (and anyone else who reads it) is free to decide whether it is a good solution for them.  And please read the post again.  I did not say 'wait forever', just for a reasonable length of time since PayPal almost always responds within that time.  And in fact, in the other cases you cite, the return page does not appear to be visited in the first place.  I said that, too, but you don't appear to have taken that in either.

Comment: @EJP I have updated my post and the meaning should now be a lot clearer. Please take the time to re-read it - properly this time, don't just skim it - to see if it makes sense to you now. You have done me a grave disservice here and your original disparaging comment and downvote were completely unjustified. In plain English, you got it wrong Can you find it in you to admit that? - because that's what's needed here.

Answer (score 0):

You should not regard or show the transaction as complete, or allow any further business action to occur, until you have actually received the money, and only the IPN tells you that.

You need to adjust what you show on your return page accordingly.

All you should really do here is thank the customer for his business and tell him that the download or the delivery or whatever it is will become available immediately PayPal has notified you of the actual transfer.

And note that it can take a lot longer than three seconds. If they chose to fund the payment from their bank account, it can take 3-5 *days:* and there is always the possibility of that process failing altogether due to insufficient funds.

So don't be too optimistic in designing your return page. The deal isn't done until the money is in the bank.

> This page show "thanks"

Good.

> and "button to allow download their last paid online contract"

Bad. That should be somewhere in 'My Account'.